# AngularJS : How to use a service to retrieve data and share it between controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm having a problem with sharing data between my controllers.

I have created a page with 2 separate controllers. One with a search form, and a second one with a table to show the results from the search.

I have created these 2 separate controllers to keep things clean and have each controller deal with its own respective part of the screen. Therefor, I've put the logic of processing the search and retrieving the results in a service which is injected into both controllers.
The search() method of the service sets a data property with the result, and the result property is set to a $scope property inside the controller.

I thought it to work like this, but it doesn't. Data is retrieved correctly and set to the service property, but it is not reflected to the controller property. Am i doing something wrong or missing something here?

Any help is much appreciated!

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/0a75uh34/3/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('searchController', [
    '$scope', 'searchService',

function ($scope, searchService) {
    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.data = searchService.data;

    $scope.submit = function () {
        searchService.search($scope.search);
    }
}]);

app.controller('searchListController', [
    '$scope', 'searchService',

function ($scope, searchService) {
    $scope.data = searchService.data;

    $scope.test = function () {
        console.log($scope.firms.length);
    }
}]);

app.factory('searchService', [
    '$http',

function ($http) {

    return {
        data: [],

        search: function (params) {
            var this$ = this;
            $http.post('/echo/json/', params)
                .success(function (result) {
                this$.data = result;
            })
                .error(function () {
                console.log('Oops...');
            });
        }

    }
}]);
```

Comment: your fiddle don't have search data and nothing happens by clicking the buttons.

Comment: I had left out the search implementation as this isn't the problem. I changed the sample code to return some dummy data: http://jsfiddle.net/ranthonissen/0a75uh34/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish the desired behavior using $interval as this sample shows:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('ServiceData', function(){
  return {
    data: [1,2,3],
    search: function() { 
      var this$ = this;
      this$.data = [1,2,3,5,6,6,7,8,9,];}
  };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval, ServiceData) {
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.data_list_1 = ServiceData.data;
  }, 100);

  $scope.doSearch = function() { ServiceData.search();};
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $interval, ServiceData){
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.data_list_2 = ServiceData.data;
  }, 100);
});
```

Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/A75rTb

Answer (score 0):

sharing data between two controllers is fun. 
First you need to create a service using factory/service pattern.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('ServiceData', function(){
  return {data:[1,2,3,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,0]};
});
```

Than you can inject this service in any controller and no matter how many controllers you creates!!

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ServiceData) {
  $scope.data = ServiceData.data;
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, ServiceData){
  $scope.data = ServiceData.data;
});
```

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCPnJQ?p=preview)

Comment: I got something similar working as well, but I want to retrieve my data from a remote WebAPI service on the click of a button not when the page loads. Within this click the search method of the service is executed and the data property is set. I can see that this works when I step through my code, but the searchService.data is'n reflected to the $scope.data

Comment: I've altered your plunkr to simulate my situation here: http://plnkr.co/edit/A75rTb?p=preview

Comment: I expected the data in the second controller to be automatically updated when the data is updated in the service. In my application I don't have a "Test" button to do that

Comment: I got it working using $interval, but this feels rather counter-intuitive to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/A75rTb